# Tensorflow-gpu in Python with Geforce Titan Z

Tags: python, python-3.x, cuda, tensorflow, anaconda

I have problems setting up tensorflow with python 3.5.3 on Windows 7. The CUDA version is 8.0 and the GPU driver is updated to the latest version.

On the machine I used, there are one Geforce titan z (two cores) and one 750ti installed on the machine. I kept getting error msgs saying the "peer access is not supported" between the two cores on the titan z card and between the titan z and 750ti.

I am wondering:
1. Is it possible to use only one GPU for the tensorflow, and let it work?
2. Is it possible to use both cores in the titan z card for tensorflow?
3. Any suggestions on the python version and anaconda version for tensorflow? Will a Linux environment solve these problems?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to use a single or multiple GPUs and specify which one to use for each operation ([link](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/using_gpu)). TensorFlow has a requirement of compute capability 3.5 for an eligible GPU. Python/linux environment doesn't affect how GPU is used.